Testing a method in a Vue3 setup component with vitest
I need to make a test for a method in a VUE3 setup in a component and nothing I have tried works.
Here is the simplified component:
<script setup>

function myFunction(number) {
   return number + 1
}

</script>

<template>
// code here

And the test:
import { MyComponent } from '@/Components/MyComponent.vue'
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {

    test('myMethodWorks', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)
        const result = wrapper.vm.$setupState.myFunction(1);
        expect(result).toBe(2)
        
    });
});


But I keep getting the error: ReferenceError: document is not defined.
I am working in a dev team and there are other tests in the Vue test folder that work fine, so I shouldn't (and couldn't) change any config files. But none of the other tests are trying to test a method from a Vue3 component - I was wondering if it is even possible to do this from a Unit test.
Even if I put in the test :
expect(true).toBe(true)
..and comment out the rest, I still get the same error.
What am I doing wrong?
